# Class option for archery + botany + potions

Tags: dnd-3.5e

I have a new player who wants to play a half-elf who is:

1. Very intelligent
2. Good at archery
3. Makes potions
4. Knows about plants and botany in order to make potions etc

We are starting at first level. All D&D 3.5 first-party content is allowed.

I cannot think of a class and skill+feat options that fit this well. Help?

Comment: What resources can be used to build characters? What kinds of characters do the other players intend to play? Will this be a short-term or long-term campaign? You've tagged this rule-as-written, but that tag's the subject of some controversy at the moment. Can you clarify your intent? (More information is almost always better with character questions. Sorry if all that comes off as abrupt. )

Comment: By "RAW" I mean anything from an official WOTS 3.5e book.

Answer (score 5):

For an intelligent potion-brewer, you will want the **Artificer** class, from Eberron Campaign Setting.

### Very intelligent

Any character can have a high Int score, but it's more useful for some than for others. Artificers run off Intelligence - it is the key ability score for their Infusions (sort of like spells), they have several of the major Knowledge skills, they can Search and Disable Device just like a rogue does, and their Artificer Knowledge also runs on it.

### Makes potions

Normally, even a spellcaster must wait until 3rd level in order to take Brew Potion. Artificers get it for free at level 2, so your buddy can start brewing a level early. They also get a craft reserve of free XP they can use to craft these potions, meaning that they don't need to use their own XP for crafting. Some of the bonus feats they get make item crafting cheaper and faster. Artificers also get Craft Construct as a bonus feat, allowing them to craft a Dedicated Wright - a construct that can craft for you while you are out adventuring, as long as you invest the GP and XP first. It's like a sweet robot butler for your potions.

At level 6, go into the Alchemist Savant class from Magic of Eberron to become the ultimate potions master (yes, even better than Snape). Their capstone ability lets them prepare a potion without putting a specific spell into it, and any time after brewing they can decide what spell the potion becomes. This can be fluffed to go with the intelligence thing - the character is *so incredibly smart* that he knew all along it that he should brew a potion of *water breathing* when he was brewing potions last week, and didn't just pull it out of his butt.

### Archery

Being an archer in D&D 3.5 is very expensive! 50 magic arrows cost as much as a magic weapon of the same bonus, and once they run out, you have to buy more. As expert craftsmen, artificers can make these arrows themselves to save on costs, and also use infusions to enhance their archery. Did the party's scout spot some orcs in the distance? Boom, the bow is now an orc-bane bow.

### Herbalism

This is a weak point for artificers, since they don't get Knowledge (Nature) or Survival. However, Profession (Herbalist) or Craft (Alchemy) is still within reach.

Comment: Nice! Also worth mentioning that the Artificer spell list has some pretty good options for archery.

Comment: Regarding the cost of archery: note that you enchant the *bow* itself, which will confer the bonuses on the ammunition used. This makes ammunition weapons pretty versatile because you can enchant the weapon itself with good generic bonuses and then cherry-pick munitions with various bonuses (in small quantities) to adapt to different situations. Much cheaper than melee weapons, where you need one weapon for each combination of bonuses :/

Comment: Worth noting: the *Dungeon Master’s Guide II* feat Apprentice has an option to apprentice to a woodsman, yielding **both** Knowledge (nature) **and** Survival as always-in-class skills. And then at 5th level, the character “graduates” and can (with DM permission) get the Mentor feat for free.

Answer (score 1):

### Requirements

**Intelligence**
Mechanically, any character who has a high ability score can be intelligent.  This is most important for wizards, but many other classes can benefit from it. Rogues come to mind, but anyone will be happy with more skill points.

This is also partially satisfied with role-playing. Roleplaying an intelligent character shouldn't be limited by whats on the character sheet. If that bothers your player, recommend that they invest in knowledge skills.

**Archery**
Half-elves don't get any bonus weapon proficiencies so taking a class with access to the appropriate weapons helps. Worst case scenario is investing a feat to get access to Martial Weapons.

They will also probably want to invest in archery feats. How many will depend on exactly how far they want to push archery. Rangers and fighters gain bonus feats, which can be focused on archery.

**Potions**
There are a few possibilities, depending on what you mean by "potion".

First, there are literal potions which can only be created with the Brew Potion feat. This would mean the character has a caster level of 3, which cuts down on the classes that could possible satisfy their requirements.

Second, there is alchemy.  The Craft(Alchemy) skill can be used to craft alchemical substances. By the rules, these aren't "potions". However, this just means that alchemical substances don't replicate spells when consumed. They still "feel" like potions in many regards, and definitely match the flavor of the other character requirements.

Finally, there is herbalism.  There is no well-defined usage of Profession(Herbalism), except earning a few silver each week.  In nearly all cases when I have had a player who wants to persue herbalism, we use Craft(Alchemy) and reflavor it a bit.

**Plants and Botany**
This is pretty easy to satisfy with the Knowledge(Nature) skill.  They may also wish to have Survival, which implies a more practical kind of talent than Knowledge(Nature).

### Specific Classes

**Ranger**
Probably the obvious option is the Ranger:  out of the box, a ranger will have a close association with nature. Many of their abilities revolve around the outdoors (track, wild empathy, animal companion, nature-themed spells).

Rangers get a combat style, one of which is archery. Pick the archery style and arm them with a bow.

**Druid**
Like rangers, druids hit the nature-theme hard.  Spells, wild shape, animal companions. Again, put points in Craft(Alchemy), Knowledge(Nature), and the Intelligence ability to meet your conditions.

For druids, archery ends up being the hardest part.  How far you want to go into the archery feat tree will depend on exactly how much spellcasting/archery they want.  If they are okay losing spellcasting ability, they could pick up a few levels of fighter or ranger to increase their archery abilities.

**Other Classes**
Really any character can fit the bill with Knowledge(Nature), Craft(Alchemy), high intelligence, and archery feats.  Most classes can meet these requirements. If your player insists that only potions created with Brew Potion are acceptable, than the list gets cut down to those classes which have a caster level.

Example - if they want to focus on archery, make a fighter. Give them high intelligence and sink skill points into Craft(Alchemy) and Knowledge(Nature). Presto! They also fit.

Comment: The problem I have with this is that potions are made by being a spellcaster and having [Brew Potion](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/feats.htm#brewPotion), not using Craft(alchemy).

Comment: Mechanically they are definitely two different things.  Otherwise though, the idea behind a potion and alchemical substance are very similar.  For developing a character concept, alchemical substances seem very similar.  I'll add a note about the Brew Potion feat though.

Comment: Yes. It's the potion part that has me. Are then any in depth official rules that cover herbalism? I'm thinking of potions that don't involve magic.

Comment: I've seen herbalism come up a lot of times. Typically it is just flavor for Alchemy or Brew Potion.

Comment: "Alchemy & Herbalists" has some rules on it, pretty sure it's not RAW though.